# Unknown host 'services.gradle.org' you may need to adjust proxy setting

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have installed android studios 2.3.3. Whenever I am creating a new project it's giving me this error : Unknown host 'services.gradle.org' you may need to adjust proxy setting. While my older projects are working fine. I have enabled Auto detect proxy settings even after that it's not working.